# Trying to make a calculator

Tags: c#, while-loop, calculator

so basically whenever i try to change the variable "restart" inside of the while loop it gives me an error saying "a local or parameter named 'restart' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter". if anyone knows how to fix this please tell me

````
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        bool restart = true;
        while (restart == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("please enter Multiply, Divide, Add Or Subtract");
            string Method = Console.ReadLine();
            if (Method == "Add")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter First Number");
                double numberOne = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Second Number");
                double numberTwo = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine(numberOne + numberTwo);
                Console.WriteLine("Would You Like To Use The Calculator Again? (true = yes, false = no)");
                bool restart = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (Method == "Subtract")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter First Number");
                double numberOne = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Second Number");
                double numberTwo = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine(numberOne - numberTwo);
                Console.WriteLine("Would You Like To Use The Calculator Again? (true = yes, false = no)");
                bool restart = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (Method == "Multiply")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter First Number");
                double numberOne = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Second Number");
                double numberTwo = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine(numberOne * numberTwo);
                Console.WriteLine("Would You Like To Use The Calculator Again? (true = yes, false = no)");
                bool restart = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else if (Method == "Divide")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter First Number");
                double numberOne = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Second Number");
                double numberTwo = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine(numberOne / numberTwo);
                Console.WriteLine("Would You Like To Use The Calculator Again? (true = yes, false = no)");
                bool restart = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error found");
                Console.WriteLine("Would You Like To Use The Calculator Again? (true = yes, false = no)");
                bool restart = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: take out the `bool`  in `bool restart = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());`. you're trying to declare a _new_ variable in the scope when that variable is declared in the outer scope.

Comment: Also note that you repeat the last two lines in every `if` block. You could move that outside of the last `else`.

Comment: @DStanley thankyou, but it has to be after every if block i believe sense the else is just for if you do something that's not "Add, Multiply, Subtract or Divide"

Comment: @Gh0ST: D Stanley is right. You have the same code in every "if" branch, so that code always runs no matter what. You can (and should) move those two lines after the closing brace of your else statement. It's important to avoid repeating the same code in different parts of your app for the sake of maintainability (if you have a bug in a line you repeat in a bunch of places, you have to find and fix all those places).

Comment: @EricJ. thankyou i understand now what they ment

Comment: Rather than declare new vars each block (ie `double numberOne`) you should declare one outside the loop and reuse it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at this part of your code:

```
bool restart = true;
while (restart == true)
{
    // Some stuff omitted...
    bool restart = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

You *redeclare* `restart`. Instead, you should just assign it like this (leave `bool` off when you use the variable after first declaring it):

```
restart = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
    bool restart = true;
    while (restart)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("please enter Multiply, Divide, Add Or Subtract");
        string method = Console.ReadLine();
        if (new[] { "Multiply", "Divide", "Add", "Subtract" }.Contains(method))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter First Number");
            double numberOne = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Second Number");
            double numberTwo = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            if (method == "Add")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numberOne + numberTwo);
            }
            else if (method == "Subtract")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numberOne - numberTwo);
            }
            else if (method == "Multiply")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numberOne * numberTwo);
            }
            else if (method == "Divide")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numberOne / numberTwo);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Would You Like To Use The Calculator Again? (true = yes, false = no)");
            restart = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error found");
            Console.WriteLine("Would You Like To Use The Calculator Again? (true = yes, false = no)");
            restart = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
```

---

Or this:

```
    Dictionary<string, Func<double, double, double>> operations =
        new Dictionary<string, Func<double, double, double>>()
        {
            { "Add", (x, y) => x + y },
            { "Subtract", (x, y) => x - y },
            { "Multiply", (x, y) => x * y },
            { "Divide", (x, y) => x / y },
        };
    
    bool restart = true;
    while (restart)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Please enter one of: {String.Join(", ", operations.Keys)}");
        string method = Console.ReadLine();
        if (operations.ContainsKey(method))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter First Number");
            double numberOne = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Second Number");
            double numberTwo = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(operations[method](numberOne, numberTwo));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error found");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Would You Like To Use The Calculator Again? (true = yes, false = no)");
        restart = Convert.ToBoolean(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

Comment: You have some code duplication :-) (see comments)

Comment: I don't believe `new[] { "Multiply, Divide, Add Or Subtract" }.Contains(method)` does what you want it to.

Comment: @EricJ. - All duplication eliminated! :-)